# How to perform Name Entity Recognition faster on large files in using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am trying to perform Name Entity Recognition on large files such as text files as large as 1GB that is about 9 million lines of text.

I have the below code that prints N.E.R outputs. So I basically do `python3 NER.py > output.txt`. However this takes so much time and doesn't even finish when I ran it for 3 hours now. How can I make this usable?

```
import nltk
import re

sentence = ""

with open("input.txt", "r") as inFile:
    sentence = inFile.read()

for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence):
    for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
        if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
            print(chunk.label(), ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk))
```

Comment: It's never going to be usable with a 1GB corpus.  Natural language processing takes time.  You'll just need to wait.  You can experiment with reading the file in 50MB chunks and processing the chunks, but then you risk missing works split across your chunk boundaries.

Comment: @TimRoberts ah okay. Thank you!